# Is glassPane painting model broken?

Tags: codenameone

I think, that something has broken in cn1 painting model. Could someone review if this is a bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

I would like to archive the following:

On a form is a label, which text is refreshed with UITimer with 1 second interval. For example:
[image]

To indicate some activity on form is used `form.setGlassPane(..)` to paint a shadow above the form. The problem is, that on label text update label is repainted, but glasspane is not repainted, that is the shadow is not painted on the label:

[image]

Test code:

```
    final Form form = new Form("Welcome", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    final Label label = new Label("..");
    Button button = new Button("Show Shade");
    form.addComponent(label);
    form.addComponent(button);

    button.addActionListener((e) -> {
        form.setGlassPane(new Painter() {

            public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {
                int wasAlpha = g.getAlpha();
                g.setAlpha(50);
                g.setColor(0x101010);
                g.fillRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
                g.setAlpha(wasAlpha);
            }
        });
    });

    new UITimer(() -> {
        label.setText(new Date().toString());
    }).schedule(1000, true, form);
    form.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be due to a fix for [issue 1680](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1680) a while back. I reopened the issue, we'll need to figure out why this failed.